# Why is this SQL giving error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following SQL code:

```
  CREATE TABLE "MY_SCHEMA"."FLIGHT" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    "SERVICE_SEQ_FK" NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SERVICE(SERVICE_SEQ)
   );
```

It gives following error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

What right parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining an *inline* foreign key, the `foreign key` keyword must not be used:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.FLIGHT 
(    
   ID             NUMBER NOT NULL, 
   SERVICE_SEQ_FK NUMBER REFERENCES SERVICE (SERVICE_SEQ)
);
```

See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses002.htm#CJAHIEIJ

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all get rid off those double quotes, they are just going to trouble you later.
2. Use an explicit name for "ID" column rather than just "ID".

   ```
   CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.FLIGHT
   (
      ID_COL NUMBER NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT SERVICE_SEQ_FK FOREIGN KEY (SERVICE_SEQ) SERVICE(SERVICE_SEQ)
   );
   ```

**Update : I think it is better to provide examples for IN-line and OUT-of-line foreign key definitions.**

Inline foreign key (part of column definition):

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
        c1 NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        c2 NUMBER REFERENCES t1(c1) );
```

Out-of-line foreign key (after column definitions):

```
CREATE TABLE t3 (
        c1 NUMBER,
        c2 NUMBER,
        CONSTRAINT t1_fk FOREIGN KEY (c1) REFERENCES t1);
```